# How to implement Android’s Data Backup Service

Tags: android

For my Android Project I tried to follow and implement Android Developers Data Backup Guidelines ( http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/backup.html ), but Data Backup and Restore doesn't work. Can someone help with examples?

Comment: This is the best sample I have found: https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/0b3758ea4e53f9bfd0b112eaa4a7dd7b7f4040f5/samples/BackupRestore

Answer (score 2):

With further investigation I figured out the steps to implement Android Data Backup and Restore. They are:

1. Add in Manifest xml file the following:
    a. `android:allowBackup="true"`   (This enables Android’s Data Backup Service)
    b. `meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key"
      android:value=”{Your unique Registration Key for Android Backup Service}”` (You must register your application package name with a backup service. To generate a key, go to http://developer.android.com/google/backup/signup.html   )
    c. `android:backupAgent=”.MyBackupAgent”` (This is the name of class that implement’s your declared backup agent class). Note1: The first character of the name is a period for the purpose of a shorthand to locate your “com.example.project.MyBackupAgent”.  Note2: If a run time Exception occurs (this may or may not happen depending on your project stucture) such as:  java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn’t find class “com.example.project.MyBackupAgent” then I suggest you Decompile your apk  (Upload your apk package in http://www.decompileandroid.com/ ) and search for the absolute path to your MyBackupAgent and insert this path for android:backupAgent=”{absolute path}.MyBackupAgent”

Here’s an example of a Manifest xml file with Backup support:

> ```
> <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.project">  
> <application  android:allowBackup="true" android:backupAgent="md5f576d3976d691fac04b078d1718cab3.MyBackupAgent">
>    <meta-data android:name="com.google.android.backup.api_key" >android:value="{Your unique Registration Key}" />
> </application>
> ```

2. Add in project your MyBackupAgent class. The BackupAgentHelper class provides a convenient wrapper around the BackupAgent class, which minimizes the amount of code you need to write. In your BackupAgentHelper, you must use one or more "helper" objects, which automatically backup and restore certain types of data, so that you do not need to implement onBackup() and onRestore().
   Note: Android currently provides backup helpers that will backup and restore complete files from SharedPreferences and internal storage.

Here’s a Java SharedPreferenceBackupHelper example for MyBackupAgent class:

```
import android.app.backup.BackupAgentHelper;  
import android.app.backup.SharedPreferencesBackupHelper;  
import android.util.Log;  

public class MyBackupAgent extends BackupAgentHelper{

    static final  String PREFS = "myprefs";
    static final  String PREFS_BACKUP_KEY = "myprefs";

    @Override  
    public void onCreate() {  
        Log.i("MyFileBackupAgent", "****** Enter BACKUP CLASS *******");  

        SharedPreferencesBackupHelper helper = new SharedPreferencesBackupHelper(this, PREFS);  
        addHelper(PREFS_BACKUP_KEY, helper);

        Log.i("MyFileBackupAgent", "****** Exit BACKUP CLASS ********");

    }

}
```

Here’s a C# Xamarin FileBackupHelper example for MyBackupAgent class:

```
public class MyBackupAgent: BackupAgentHelper  
{  
 string myProtectData = "File.bin";  
 string myPersistentData = "Data.bin";  
 string myDBase = "Database.db";  


    public override void OnCreate()  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine ("****** Enter Backup Files Helpers *********");  
        base.OnCreate ();  

        try  
        {  
            FileBackupHelper dbkh = new FileBackupHelper (this, myProtectData);  
            this.AddHelper ("PROTECT_backup", dbkh);  

            FileBackupHelper persisth = new FileBackupHelper (this, myPersistentData);  
            this.AddHelper ("PERSIST_backup", persisth);  

            FileBackupHelper dbh = new FileBackupHelper (this, myDBase);  
            this.AddHelper ("DATABASE_backup", dbh);  
            Console.WriteLine ("********* All 3 files backuped *********");  
        }  
        catch {  
            Console.WriteLine ("******* Backup AddHelper Exception ERROR *********");  
        }  
        Console.WriteLine ("******** Exit Backup Files Helpers ********");  
    }  


    public override void OnBackup(ParcelFileDescriptor oldState, BackupDataOutput data, ParcelFileDescriptor newState)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine ("****** Override OnBackup called ******");  
        base.OnBackup(oldState, data, newState);  
    }  

    public override void OnRestore (BackupDataInput data, int appVersionCode, ParcelFileDescriptor newState)  
    {  
        Console.WriteLine ("****** Override OnRestore called ******");  
        base.OnRestore(data, appVersionCode, newState);  
    }  
}
```

3. To perform a backup, your code should make a backup request by calling the dataChanged(). A backup request does not result in an immediate call to your onBackup() method. Instead, the Backup Manager waits for an appropriate time*, then performs backup for all applications that have requested a backup since the last backup was performed. Note, The Backup Manager Service responds every hour as long as at least one DataChanged() was called in-between the hour since the last data backup request.

For test purposes, an immediate backup can be performed with the Android SDK Command Prompt Tool.   Try these commands:

**To ensure Data Backup Enabled:**

> adb shell bmgr enable true

**To request a Data Backup:**

> adb shell bmgr backup

**To initiate a Data Backup:**

> adb shell bmgr run

**To uninstall your App:**

> adb uninstall

**Then install your App**:

> adb install

4. What about your phone device Backup settings?   Make sure a WiFi connection is established. Also, under device Settings, make sure "Back up my data" and "Automatic restore" are checked and you have entered in a valid Backup Account email id.
5. Lastly, to track your Backup upload time stamps, use [www.google.com/settings/dashboard](https://www.google.com/settings/dashboard) (this is your personal google account that matches your google account in your Android phone device Backup settings)